# How to sequence async calls with Promises in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, facebook-messenger

I am new to Javascript and having trouble understanding how to make my functions run after one another. I want to use Promise to achieve this.

I am following Facebook Messenger tutorial to make a chat bot. Basically, I want to send messages one after another.

If I call the following lines:

```
sendTextMessage(recipientID, "1");
sendTextMessage(recipientID, "2");
sendTextMessage(recipientID, "3");
sendTextMessage(recipientID, "4");
sendTextMessage(recipientID, "5");
```

**I want the message "1" to be sent first. Then, "2", "3" and so on. (instead of being sent in random order, which is the problem here.)**

---

Here are the relevant helper functions.

```js
function sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: messageText
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}
```

Here is callSendAPI function.

```js
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;

      if (messageId) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s", 
          messageId, recipientId);
      } else {
      console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s", 
        recipientId);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Failed calling Send API", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
    }
  });  
}
```

---

I have been stuck for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried this, but it didn't work. =(

```
sendTextMessage(recipientID, "1")
.then(sendTextMessage(recipientID, "2"))
.then(sendTextMessage(recipientID, "3"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, make your two helper functions return promises. So in `callSendAPI` you create and return one, and `sendTextMessage` should just return that same promise it gets from `callSendAPI`. Finally, make sure to pass functions to your `then` calls, instead of *executing* a function. You can use `.bind()` to create a new function from an existing one and specify the arguments that should be passed when called.

```
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { // ***
        request({
            uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
            qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
            method: 'POST',
            json: messageData
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
                var messageId = body.message_id;
                if (messageId) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s", 
                                messageId, recipientId);
                } else {
                    console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s", 
                                recipientId);
                }
                resolve(body); // ***
            } else {
                console.error("Failed calling Send API", response.statusCode,
                              response.statusMessage, body.error);
                reject(body.error); // ***
            }
        });
    });
}

function sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText) {
    var messageData = {
        recipient: {
            id: recipientId
        },
        message: {
            text: messageText
        }
    };
    return callSendAPI(messageData); // *** returns promise
}

sendTextMessage(recipientID, "1")
.then(sendTextMessage.bind(null, recipientID, "2")) // *** pass a function reference
.then(sendTextMessage.bind(null, recipientID, "3"))
.catch(function (body) {
     console.log('aborted');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there is no promise, that is why it is not working.
`request` package is not promise compatible but you can install `request-promise` which is a wrapper for `request` with `bluebird`.

Assuming, you are using `request-promise` your example would look like this :

```
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  // return the promise so you can use the promise where you call the function
  return request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData
      }).then( function(body) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;

      if (messageId) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s", 
          messageId, recipientId);
      } else {
      console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s", 
        recipientId);
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Failed calling Send API", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
    });
}
```

And for the other function :

```
function sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: messageText
    }
  };

  return callSendAPI(messageData);
}
```

Notice that you have to return the promise otherwise it is not usable by the line calling the function.